# How to Get Value of Visible Cell in a Table after Filtering - only working for 1st value

Tags: excel, vba, filter, visible

I want to get the value of a cell in a filtered table. It only seems to work for the first value, but from there it counts the hidden values as well.

I am trying to get extra information on specific values in a table. It is kind of a step by step filtering process for some requests. A Combo Box is used to select a specific area of interest, which then shows the "title" of all the values within that area in a ListBox. Then, it should be possible to see a detailed description of a request which is selected in the ListBox.

When a request is selected in the ListBox, it uses the index number to find the right row in the table and get the description from there.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim IndexNmr As Integer

    ComboValue = ComboBox1.Value

   'Store Table Object to a variable and clear all filters
    Set tbl = Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Tabel1")
    tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    'Filter Table Object based on ComboValue
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
        ComboValue

    'Find selected index in List Box
     For x = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
         If ListBox1.Selected(x) = True Then
             IndexNmr = x + 1
         End If
     Next x

     'Find Caption in Table based on the index number
     CaptionString = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(10).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(IndexNmr).Value
     Label1.Caption = CaptionString

End Sub
```

It only seems to work for the first visible value, which I can produce by:

```
`CaptionString = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(10).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Value`
```

But when the IndexNmr is ex. 2, it just takes the next row below the first visible one, even though it is hidden.

[An example of the Table data and filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jugA5.png)

Comment: Can you post an example of the table with sample data that shows how your code is working with the data?

Comment: @PeterT I have added an image which shows the set up and a small part of the table. As you can see it takes the first value in fine. But when I click on index number two in the ListBox, and IndexNmr becomes 2+1 which should get the right description (problemstilling) it instead finds a row that is hidden between the two.

Comment: BTW with your `For x = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1` loop you're getting the last selected element index (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, as you have seen, `SpecialCells` doesn't work like that (pitty, seems like it should)

You'll have to find a different way to access the n'th visible row.  Here's a demo of one way

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim lr As ListRow

    Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)

    Set lr = FindNthVisibleRow(lo, 2)

    If Not lr Is Nothing Then Debug.Print lr.Range.Address

End Sub

Function FindNthVisibleRow(lo As ListObject, Idx As Long) As ListRow
    Dim RwCnt As Long
    Dim lr As ListRow

    If Idx <= 0 Then Exit Function    
    For Each lr In lo.ListRows
        If lr.Range.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            RwCnt = RwCnt + 1
            If Idx = RwCnt Then
                Set FindNthVisibleRow = lr
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```